# Lookup function in rdlc reports - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc, lookup

I have an rdlc report created in vs.net 2010 that requires the use of the lookup function available in reporting services 2008 R2 (I just assumed it would be available in the rdlc file.) This local report uses custom business objects and functionality already available within a web application, so I don't think it can be converted to a server report. The employee dataset is a list of employee objects, each object containing financial data along with office and department properties. The report is grouped by office, then department, then employee, with each employee displaying financial details. However, there is a special employee for each office that I need to display, but not include in the list of all other employees. This information needs to be displayed at the end of each office's information and I had planned on simply adding a new row to the report and using the lookup function from the employee dataset against another dataset containing the financial data for this special employee. This special employee is of the same type as a normal employee, so the lookup would be based on the office property.

So my question is, am I overlooking something or is the lookup function truly not available in the rdlc files created using vs.net 2010? If it's not available, any suggestions on how I might achieve this kind of lookup functionality?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Hi Eric, did you get a workaround with this scenario? I started working with a report RDLC that i'd converted from an old ReportServer (rdl) that uses Lookup function, I thinked using Custom Code but it don't allow to access DataSets under custom code.